# Can the spacing of a defintion list be adjusted in html/css?

Tags: html, css

I'd like a defintion list that looks like:

```
 term 1
   definition 1
 term 2
   definition 2
```

rather than

```
 term 1
      definition 1
 term 2
      definition 2
```

What's the easiest way to to this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a margin-left declaration to the `<dd>` element:

```
dd { margin-left: 15px; }
```

You'll have to adjust the amount to whatever suits your needs, obviously.

Answer (score 1):

Or:

```
dd {
   margin-left: 2em;
}
```

Which will indent 2 characters in.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the `margin-left` attribute for the `dd` tag:

```
dd {
    margin-left: 20px;
}
```